# SIGSEV when calling JAVA callback method from native code after multiple calls

Tags: java, jna

I am using JNA to pass a callback function from Java to native code. I am able to call the java inteface method ok, the problem is after about 40 calls of the function i get a SIGSEV and the program terminates.

The SIGSEV occurs at the line when the native code calls the method.

Is this related so some garbage collection on the Java function handle?  Is there a way to prevent this?

Note: The closest thread on the sight was "SIGSEV when calling Java method from native pthread".  He seemed solve his problem on the native side though by making things global.

I have tried making the java method synchronous but this has not helped.  I also modified the native call to launch a pthread and then call the java method.  When doing this, the method can be called maybe 1000 times then i get the SIGSEV

on the java side I have

---

```
public  interface handler extends Callback {
    void invoke();

}
```

---

```
static class  test_start implements handler {
    public synchronized void invoke() {
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }
}
```

---

Comment: Please show how you use/register the callback. It is always a good idea to create a self contained sample of code, that allows to see the whole problem. In this case the context of the handler and its registration is important.

Comment: You still provide to little context - what are BB.SM? Please create a minimal, runnable sample, that demonstrates your problem. Even if helpers here can't run it because the library is missing, you narrow down your problem and helpers can see where your code goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that you suspect GC to be your problem, which is also [documented in JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/CallbacksAndClosures.md).

Summary: You'll need to keep a strong reference to your Callback Handler on the java side to prevent garbage collection.

The implementation is highly dependent on your architecture. If your handler is global, you can save it in a static field (GC will normally collect static field data only when class is unloaded). If your handler is tied to a concrete java class, you could use a static WeakHashMap to keep the reference until the java object is collected (assuming this also indicates, that the native side will not call the handler anymore). If the handler is tied to a fixed lifecycle, I would implement an AutoCloseable helper object, that unregisters your handler on close.

It should be noted, that in all implementations, you must make sure that your handler is kept referenced. For the AutoClosable implementation running [Reference#reachabilityFence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence-java.lang.Object-)​ from the close method after the handler is unregister would be a sane decision.